# How to make image float out of a cleared wrapper?

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-position

Consider this example: http://jsfiddle.net/K4qKk/

Since the wrapper is cleared properly, so the image height extended the wrapper height.

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="b1"> B1 </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lh6.ggpht.com/zoUh3l0iIQXaV83M32fDab8LtsBNCVL7FX-gbs5NL-8ulFYYTkZkZvOh1KquPNg8aw5CckHNSDpdo4nDg4CH-9jiEJ3xLU_rFymtZM9K" />
    </div>
    <div class="b2"> B2 </div>
    <div class="b3"> B3 </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>
```

What I want is the wrapper height only extend to the height of B1, B2, B3, and make the image look like it was taken out of the wrapper, is it possible?

[image]

Comment: This may be what you're looking for http://jsfiddle.net/K4qKk/4/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display: inline-block` for your divs and `.image`, set the height of the image wrapper and use some negative margins to center the image inside its wrapper.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/d6mnd/)**

Comment: this technique seems good but you don't have to use `display:inline-block`, you can stick with `float:left;` see here : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/d6mnd/1/

Comment: @web-tiki the idea of using `inline-block` may be because of the image posted in the OP's question.